# Penetration Depth into a Planar Polygon

Tags: collision-detection, physics

I'm working on a self-made physics engine, and I'm wondering about the best way to calculate the penetration depth into a polygon that lies in a plane given that resolution must occur along the polygon's normal.

My current system correctly uses GJK/EPA to detect if a polygon that lies in a plane is intersecting a 3D collider. However, in a case such as the one illustrated below, EPA would not calculate the separating axis to be along the plane normal, but rather outwards parallel to the plane, as that is the direction of minimum penetration.

[image: The sphere will be pushed outwards.]

My first thought was to simply manually alter the resolution direction. After GJK detects a collision, I can calculate the support mapping of the polygon in the opposite direction of the plane's normal, then take its perpendicular distance from the plane as its penetration depth. However, in a case such as the one below, this would yield an incorrect penetration depth, as the support point does not project onto the plane.

[image: The support point yields an inaccurate penetration depth.]

What's the best way to go about getting the penetration depth into the polygon, but only considering penetration of points on the polygon that actually project onto the polygon?

Comment: Why not simply use the lowest signed distance from each of the points with the plane, and then exclude points which are clipped by the outer edges of the plane? Simply take the normal of the plane, and rotate it outwards, and place the plane at each of the 4 corners of the plane? Then you have 4 planes with which to clip the outside points

Comment: Generally, I'm trying to avoid using solutions that poll all points, as I'm also using rounded colliders such as spheres and capsules with infinite points. With a discrete set of points, though, how would you find the correct depth after removing a point? (For example, if I clipped the support mapped point in my second figure above, wouldn't I also lose the edge on which the correct penetration depth projects?)

Comment: Although I do think you're onto something in that I can just treat each plane as a hull by giving it some artificial thickness in the direction opposite its normal, then using the contact point to calculate penetration depth...